# Consulta en MVC SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, mvc, pdf

Tengo una gran duda, y es bastante complicada de explicar por lo que lo haré con un ejemplo. 
Supongamos que soy un empleado de una empresa que posee clientes que nos compran planes. Cada plan posee un código alfanumérico que lo hace único. Ese plan puede ser en un conjunto de 180 ó 300 cuotas. Entonces, necesito una web en la que pueda ingresar el código alfanumérico de la solicitud y que esta me muestre un PDF con un determinado fondo. Este es mi dilema, porque solo puedo ingresar el valor alfanumérico. Entonces, ¿Cómo hago para que al ingresar el valor de la solicitud, dependiendo de las cuotas del plan, me muestre un PDF con fondo azul-verde? Es decir, si las cuotas son 300, quiero que el PDF sea azul, si son 180 quiero que sea verde.

Actualmente, este es mi código:

**Conexion SQL:**

```
public List<Cuotas> cargarDatosPDF(string sol)
        {
            List<Cuotas> salida = new List<Cuotas>();
            //string con = "cadena;
            using (SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(con))
            {
                conexion.Open();
                string sql = "SELECT apellido" + "', '" + "nombre AS Persona," +
                    " domicilio, numero, dpto, piso, localidad, barrio, " +
                    "provincia, dninumero," +
                    "solicitud, DATENAME(M,vencimiento) " + "'/ '" + "CAST(DATEPART(yyyy,vencimiento) AS VARCHAR) AS Emision," +
                    "codigo, monto, " +
                    "descplanactual, valnom," +
                    "telefono, barras " +
                    "FROM V_CuetaWeb " +
                    " WHERE solicitud = @sol " +
                    " AND ancantcuoplan IN (48, 60,90,120,180, 300,330) " +
                    " AND DATEPART(mm, vencimiento) = DATEPART(mm, GETDATE()) ";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conexion);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sol", sol);
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        string person = dr["persona"]?.ToString();
                        string domicilio = dr["domicilio"]?.ToString();
                        string numero = dr["numero"]?.ToString();
                        string dpto = dr["dpto"]?.ToString();
                        string piso = dr["piso"]?.ToString();
                        string localidad = dr["localidad"]?.ToString();
                        string barrio = dr["barrio"]?.ToString();
                        string provincia = dr["provincia"]?.ToString();
                        double? dni = Convert.ToDouble(dr["dninumero"]?.ToString());
                        string soli = dr["solicitud"]?.ToString();
                        DateTime? em = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["Emision"]?.ToString());
                        string codigo = dr["codigo"]?.ToString();
                        decimal? monto = Convert.ToDecimal(dr["monto"]?.ToString());
                        string desc = dr["descplanactual"]?.ToString();
                        double? valnom = Convert.ToDouble(dr["valnom"]?.ToString());
                        string tel = dr["telefono"]?.ToString();
                        string barras = dr["barras"]?.ToString();
                        Cuotas p = new Cuotas(person, domicilio, numero, dpto, piso, localidad,barrio, provincia, dni, soli,em, codigo, monto,
                            desc,valnom,tel,barras);
                        salida.Add(p);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex) {

                        throw ex;
                    }
                }
                conexion.Close();
                return salida;
            }
        }
```

**ancantcuotas** es la cantidad de cuotas que posee el plan. Como no sé como hacerlo, pensé que ingresandolo así podría funcionar y desde el controlador pregunto que valor tiene pero ahí no se me ha ocurrido como hacerlo.

**Controlador:**

```
public ActionResult Pdf(string solicitud)
        {
            try
            {
                ConexionSQL c = new ConexionSQL();

                // usar inlinne para ver online - attachment para descarga automática
                Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + solicitud + ".pdf\"");
                var suscriptor = c.cargarDatosPDF(solicitud);
                var caracteres = Convert.ToString(solicitud).Length;
                if (caracteres <= 4 || caracteres > 7)
                {
                    ViewData["Mensaje"] = "La cantidad de caracteres no puede ser menor a 5 (cinco) ni mayor a 7 (siete).";
                    return View("Index");
                }
                if (suscriptor.Count <= 0)
                {
                    ViewData["Mensaje"] = "Lo sentimos, la solicitud no existe.";
                    return View("Index");
                }

                if ((caracteres >= 5 && caracteres <= 7) && suscriptor.Count > 0)
                {
                    var reporte = new PartialViewAsPdf("Pdf", c.cargarDatosPDF(solicitud));
                    return reporte;
                }
                else
                {
                    return View("Index");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {

                return Content(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Tienes la opción de poder cambiar el color al PDF? Me refiero a que si al momento de armar el archivo, puedes pasarle colores al fondo por código? Si es así, donde lo haces?

Comment: No, no. Solo puedes ingresar el valor del código de la solicitud. Igual, ya lo solucioné. Gracias. @PauloUrbanoRivera

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo solucioné agregando el valor de la cantidad de cuotas a la consulta:

```
public List<Certificados> cargarDatosPDF(string sol)
        {
            List<Certificados> salida = new List<Certificados>();
            //string con = "cadena";
            using (SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(con))
            {
                conexion.Open();
                string sql = "SELECT apellido " + " + ', ' + " + " nombre AS Persona," +
                    " domicilio, numero, dpto, piso, localidad, barrio, " +
                    "provincia, dninumero," +
                    "solicitud, DATENAME(M,vencimiento) " + " + '/ ' + " + "CAST(DATEPART(yyyy,vencimiento) AS VARCHAR) AS Emision," +
                    "codigo, monto, " +
                    "descplanactual, valnom," +
                    "telefono, barras, " +
                    "ancantcuoplan " +
                    " FROM V_CuetaWeb " +
                    " WHERE solicitud = @sol " +
                    " AND DATEPART(mm, vencimiento) = DATEPART(mm, GETDATE()) ";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conexion);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sol", sol);
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        string person = dr["persona"]?.ToString();
                        string domicilio = dr["domicilio"]?.ToString();
                        string numero = dr["numero"]?.ToString();
                        string dpto = dr["dpto"]?.ToString();
                        string piso = dr["piso"]?.ToString();
                        string localidad = dr["localidad"]?.ToString();
                        string barrio = dr["barrio"]?.ToString();
                        string provincia = dr["provincia"]?.ToString();
                        double dni = Convert.ToDouble(dr["dninumero"]?.ToString());
                        string soli = dr["solicitud"]?.ToString();
                        DateTime em = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["Emision"]?.ToString());
                        string codigo = dr["codigo"]?.ToString();
                        decimal? monto = Convert.ToDecimal(dr["monto"]?.ToString());
                        string desc = dr["descplanactual"]?.ToString();
                        double? valnom = Convert.ToDouble(dr["valnom"]?.ToString());
                        string tel = dr["telefono"]?.ToString();
                        string barras = dr["barras"]?.ToString();
                        int cantidadCuotas = Convert.ToInt32(dr["ancantcuoplan"]?.ToString());
                        Certificados p = new Certificados(person, domicilio, numero, dpto, piso, localidad, barrio, provincia, dni, soli, em, codigo, monto,
                            desc, valnom, tel, barras, cantidadCuotas);
                        salida.Add(p);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {

                        throw ex;
                    }
                }
                conexion.Close();
                return salida;
            }
        }
```

Y desde el **controlador**, realizo la consulta:

```
public ActionResult Pdf(string solicitud)
        {
            try
            {
                ConexionSQL c = new ConexionSQL();

                // usar inlinne para ver online - attachment para descarga automática
                Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + solicitud + ".pdf\"");
                var suscriptor = c.cargarDatosPDF(solicitud);
                var caracteres = Convert.ToString(solicitud).Length;
                if (suscriptor[0].cantCuo == 48)
                {
                    var reporte = new PartialViewAsPdf("Pdf48", c.cargarDatosPDF(solicitud));
                    return reporte;
                }
                else if (suscriptor[0].cantCuo == 60)
                {
                    var reporte = new PartialViewAsPdf("Pdf60", c.cargarDatosPDF(solicitud));
                    return reporte;
                }
                else if (suscriptor[0].cantCuo == 90)
                {
                    var reporte = new PartialViewAsPdf("Pdf90", c.cargarDatosPDF(solicitud));
                    return reporte;
                }
                else if (suscriptor[0].cantCuo == 120)
                {
                    var reporte = new PartialViewAsPdf("Pdf120", c.cargarDatosPDF(solicitud));
                    return reporte;
                }
                else if (suscriptor[0].cantCuo == 180)
                {
                    var reporte = new PartialViewAsPdf("Pdf180", c.cargarDatosPDF(solicitud));
                    return reporte;
                }
                else if (suscriptor[0].cantCuo == 300)
                {
                    var reporte = new PartialViewAsPdf("Pdf300", c.cargarDatosPDF(solicitud));
                    return reporte;
                }
                else if (suscriptor[0].cantCuo == 330)
                {
                    var reporte = new PartialViewAsPdf("Pdf330", c.cargarDatosPDF(solicitud));
                    return reporte;
                }
                else
                {
                    ViewData["Mensaje"] = "Lo sentimos, no existe un plan de cuotas para esta solicitud.";
                    return View("Index");
                }
                //if (caracteres <= 4 || caracteres > 7)
                //{
                //    ViewData["Mensaje"] = "La cantidad de caracteres no puede ser menor a 5 (cinco) ni mayor a 7 (siete).";
                //    return View("Index");
                //}
                //if (suscriptor.Count <= 0)
                //{
                //    ViewData["Mensaje"] = "Lo sentimos, la solicitud no existe.";
                //    return View("Index");
                //}

                //if ((caracteres >= 5 && caracteres <= 7) && suscriptor.Count > 0)
                //{
                //    var reporte = new PartialViewAsPdf("Pdf330", c.cargarDatosPDF(solicitud));
                //    return reporte;
                //}
                //else
                //{
                //    return View("Index");
                //}
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                return Content(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```